# tsParticles links with multiple colors

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to assign multiple colors to links in tsParticles.

For particles themselves, it's straightforward:

```
        color: {
            value: ["#03dac6", "#fac561", "#000000"],
                        animation: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 40,
                sync: false
            }
        },
```

Same does not work for link. I want to use identical colors as particles.

```js
tsParticles.load("tsparticles", {
    particles: {
        number: {
            value: 400
        },
        color: {
            value: ["#03dac6", "#fac561", "#000000"],
                        animation: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 40,
                sync: false
            }
        },
        shape: {
            type: "circle",
        },
        size: {
            value: 2,
            random: true,
            animation: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 16,
                minimumValue: 0.1,
                sync: false
            }
        },
        links: {
            enable: true,
            distance: 100,
            color: "random",
            opacity: 1,
            width: 1
        },
        move: {
            enable: true,
        },
    },

    detectRetina: true,
});
```

```css
#tsparticles {
    /*   background; */
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #212b29;
    height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>tsparticles </title>
    <!-- Import app.css from root directory -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- tsparticles div dom -->
    <div id="tsparticles"></div>
   <!-- Import cdn -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tsparticles/1.18.11/tsparticles.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Import app.js from root directory -->
    <script src="/app.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try using "mix" instead of "random" in the `links.color` value. Having the same color as particles could be meaningless if two particles have different color and are linked together.

Comment: @Caelan Nah, "mix" kills the lines entirely.

Comment: Sorry, it’s “mid”

Comment: @Caelan nope, that neither.

Comment: Ok "mid" was an internal value, "random" is the right value, as you can see here: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/rNvpGYE